# Efficient algorithm to compute combinations with repetitions of an array adding up to given sum

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, counting

So in a personal C++ project I am faced with a problem. I am rephrasing it as follows :

Given an array of *n* elements (e.g. [1, 3, 5], with n = 3 elements) where the number at the *i*th position denotes how many possible values the number at *i*th index can take (e.g here the first element can take 1 value which is 0; the second element can take 3 values from among 0,1,2; the third element can take 5 values from among 0,1,2,3,4).

I need to list all possible such arrays of length *n* that sum up to *less than or equal to* a given number *k*.
Here is an example :

**Input 1**:

input array = [2,2];
k = 2

**Output 1**:

[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]

Also, for instance :

**Input 2**:

input array = [2,2];
k = 1

**Output 2**:

[0,0], [0,1], [1,0]

**The issue** :

I have coded up a simple recursive and a simple iterative solution, which enumerates all arrays and *only keeps those which have sum less than k*. The problem with these is that for the case where **n is large and k = 1**, my code takes very long to run, since it enumerates all the cases and keeps a few.

I cannot see any overlapping sub-problems so I feel DP and memoization isn't applicable. How can I write the required C++ code for this that works?

Here is my code for the iterative version :

```
// enumerates all arrays which sum up to k

vector<vector<int> > count_all_arrays(vector<int> input_array, int k){

    vector<vector<int> > arr;
    int n = (int)input_array.size();

    // make auxilliary array with elements

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vector<int> temp(input_array[i]);
        std::iota(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0);
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }

    // computes combinations

    vector<int> temp(n);
    vector<vector<int> > answers;
    vector<int> indices(n, 0);
    int next;

    while(1){ 
        temp.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            temp.push_back(arr[i][indices[i]]);  
        long long int total = accumulate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0);
        if(total <= k)
            answers.push_back(temp);
        next = n - 1; 
        while (next >= 0 &&  
              (indices[next] + 1 >= (int)arr[next].size())) 
            next--; 
        if (next < 0) 
            break; 
        indices[next]++; 
        for (int i = next + 1; i < n; i++) 
            indices[i] = 0; 
    }
    return answers;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the recursive version? That'll probably be easier to optimize.

Comment: DP seems applicable. Consider [6,6,6,6] with k=14. Partial solutions [4,3,x,x] and [2,5,x,x] both result in subproblem [6,6] with k=7.

Comment: @user3386109 If the OP just needs to count the total number of such arrays then you can DP, but if they need to actually enumerate all the arrays then it's probably easiest to just use recursion with some simple checks to prevent from generating invalid arrays.

Comment: @BessieTheCow I lost the recursive version in some 200 files, but it was approximately like the following : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinations-with-repetitions/

Comment: @user3386109 I do need to explicitly list all such arrays, yeah :(

Comment: @BessieTheCow I theoretically get that one just needs to prune the search tree during recursion, but recursion gets bad when I have an array of length 30 or larger. I'd still be okay with a recursive version that's optimized though, since mine was totally basic.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Having a list of lists that solve a particular subproblem will be faster than recreating those lists umpteen times with recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty simple recursive task:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std;

int arr[] = {2, 2};
int n = 2;
int k = 2;

void gen(int pos, int sum, string s){
    if(pos == n){
        cout<<"["<<s<<" ]"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr[pos]; i++){
        if(sum + i > k) return;
        gen(pos + 1, sum + i, s + " " + to_string(i));
    }
}

int main(){
    gen(0, 0, "");
    return 0;
}
```

Just generate all possibilities for each slot of the array and for each choice, take the sum to the evaluation of the next slot.

When `n` is large and `k = 1`, it's natural that it takes O(n), since you will have:

```
[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0]
          ...
[0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I figured it out myself, I did some hacky reference passing to make my version of the recursion code faster. This works too though, thanks for taking time to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You should use dp to make it fast in everycase. With dp[i][j] mean how many ways you use first j element to create a sum which is less than or equal i.

```
dp[i][j] = dp[

for (int l = 0; l <= i; l++) 
    dp[i][j] += dp[l][j] + min(i-l+1, input[j])
```

The result is dp[k,n]